# Make a specific controller grab views from a subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Let's say I have a base controller class named Foo and an instance of this controller named Bar.

I need Bar to search for views in the following folders:

```
~\Views\Foo\Bar
~\Views\Foo\Shared
~\Views\Bar
~\Views\Shared
```

But I want other controllers to work same as before, which is to look for views just in:

```
~\Views\ControllerName
~\Views\Shared
```

Is it possible to achieve in asp.net-mvc?

The solution doesn't have to be clever enough to know that the base controller class is named Foo.

Comment: You will have to write a custom view engine to achieve this.

Comment: Read my post about creating a view engine (you can use it directly, you just have to define some conventions for it) http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/04/18/How-To-Create-Your-Own-AspNet-Mvc-View-Engine-From-Scratch.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of dirty approach, but you can try this in your Base Controller (`Foo`):

```
protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
    {
        foreach (var engine in ViewEngineCollection.OfType<VirtualPathProviderViewEngine>())
        {
            var newViewLocations = engine.FileExtensions.Select(ext => "~/Views/Foo/{1}/{0}." + ext).ToList();
            newViewLocations.AddRange(engine.ViewLocationFormats);
            engine.ViewLocationFormats = newViewLocations.ToArray();
        }
    }

    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
}

protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
    {
        foreach (var engine in ViewEngineCollection.OfType<VirtualPathProviderViewEngine>())
        {
            var removeViewLocations = engine.FileExtensions.Select(ext => "~/Views/Foo/{1}/{0}." + ext).ToList();
            var removedLocations = engine.ViewLocationFormats.ToList();
            removedLocations.RemoveAll(x => removeViewLocations.Contains(x));
            engine.ViewLocationFormats = removedLocations.ToArray();
        }
    }

    base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but I have one slight problem with it. I load a view from ~/Views/Foo/ and it loads fine. I load a partial from inside of that view (also located in ~/Views/Foo/) and it also loads fine. Then I try to load another partial from inside that partial and I get an error informing me that it was not found (the list of searched directories doesn't include any of the ~/Views/Foo/ ones). I still need to conduct further testing though.

Comment: Put a break-point at the beginning of the `OnResultExecuted` method and see if it's called before your partial renders the inner partial.

Comment: I put the breakpoint in OnResultExecuted, but it doesn't seem to run before the inner partial. It doesn't even seem to run before the first partial.